# Using Parrallel array and user input

Tags: java, arrays, jgrasp

For my program I have to create a bunch of methods but im stuck on starting it. basically a program to store types of trees and number of seeds. I have the list of trees in an array and want to put the number of seeds for each tree in a parrallel array, i feel like im taking the right step, but an not really getting the logic correct.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class seedFarmer {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
         }
   public static int getNumEachTree() { 
      String[] treeTypes = {"Fir" , "Pine" , "Spruce"};
      int[] numTrees = new int[treeTypes.length];
      int numofTrees = getNumEachTree();

       for (int index = 0; index < numTrees.length; index++) {

             numTrees[index] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of seeds you want to plant for: " + treeTypes[index]));
      }
     return numTrees;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're main problem is here:

```
   public static int getNumEachTree() { 
      String[] treeTypes = {"Fir" , "Pine" , "Spruce"};
      int[] numTrees = new int[treeTypes.length];
      int numofTrees = getNumEachTree();                  <--HERE
```

You are calling getNumEachTree() causing a recursive habit that never ends. The function will never stop calling itself as it has no check for whether to call itself or not and so will loop forever.

Also you are never using  numofTrees so why break your code with it? I assume it is supposed to be the return value? Maybe you intended on calling that function from main? You are returning numTrees when you should be returning an int, not an array of ints.

I don't understand what the purpose of this code is entirely but just a few syntax point outs. Your logic seems okay.